# How to Get product from cart and add it again

Tags: product, cart, order-splitting

I want to get all the product from cart in a array. and i want to remove all the products from cart. after that i want to add the same products with same quantity and options which are selected by customer again in the cart based on some conditions. i did the following.

1) Save all the products in a array which are available in cart. Using following code.

```
$quote = $this->getQuote();

$i=0;

foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $bufferItems[$i] = $item;
        $i++;
}
```

2) Remove all the products from cart using following code.

```
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $quote->getItemsCollection()->removeItemByKey($item->getId());
}
```

Up to this everything is working fine.

Now i don't know how to add the product back to the cart... can any one help me.

i did the following which is not working.

```
1) $quote->addProduct($bufferItems[1]);
2) $quote->addItem($bufferItems[1]);
```

Comment: Can I please ask why are you doing this? Why can't you just remove the products you don't want to be in the cart, and update the rest? It's much simpler and with fewer headakes

Comment: i am trying to split the order. once customer finish the order process. each product will became separate order. then only admin can assign the product to respective vendor.